# netcdf.reDef changes seen only within matlab

Tags: matlab, netcdf

When changing the name of a variable in a netcdf file I see the change only within Matlab.

In particular, I created a netcdf file with matlab via `nccreate` and `ncwrite`:

```
cd $PATH

ncfile = 'test.nc';

nccreate(ncfile,'Var1','Dimensions',{'time',20},'DeflateLevel',5);

ncwrite(ncfile,'Var1',rand(1,20),1);
ncwriteatt(ncfile,'Var1','Units','[m/s]');
```

By checking within Matlab (`ncdisp`) and via shell (`ncdump`), it results that the variable name is the same:

```
 ncdisp('test.nc')
```

> ```
> Source:
>        $PATH/test.nc Format:
>        netcdf4_classic Dimensions:
>        time = 20 Variables:
> Var1
>        Size:       20x1
>        Dimensions: time
>        Datatype:   double
>        Attributes:
>                    Units = '[m/s]'
> ```

```
$ ncdump -h test.nc
```

> ```
> netcdf test { dimensions:     time = 20 ; variables:  double Var1(time) ;
>     Var1:Units = "[m/s]" ; }
> ```

However, when I change the variable's name using Matlab:

```
cd $PATH

% Open netCDF file.
ncid = netcdf.open('test.nc','NC_WRITE');


% Put file in define mode.=
netcdf.reDef(ncid)


% Get name of first variable
[varname, xtype, varDimIDs, varAtts] = netcdf.inqVar(ncid,0);

varname


% Rename the variable, using a capital letter to start the name.
netcdf.renameVar(ncid,0,'velocity')


% Verify that the name of the variable changed.
[varname, xtype, varDimIDs, varAtts] = netcdf.inqVar(ncid,0);

varname
```

> ```
> varname =
>
>     'Var1'
>
>
> varname =
>
>     'velocity'
> ```

now, the change is seen only by Matlab:

```
ncdisp('test.nc')
```

> ```
> Source:
>        $PATH/test.nc Format:
>        netcdf4_classic Dimensions:
>        time = 20 Variables:
> velocity
>        Size:       20x1
>        Dimensions: time
>        Datatype:   double
>        Attributes:
>                    Units = '[m/s]'
> ```

```
$ ncdump -h test.nc
```

> ```
> netcdf test { dimensions:     time = 20 ; variables:  double Var1(time) ;
>     Var1:Units = "[m/s]" ; }
> ```

in fact `ncdump` still sees a variable called Var1.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Are you forgetting to overwrite test.nc after the rename?

Comment: @EricBridger How would I do that? I followed the instructions [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/netcdf.renamevar.html), where it is not mentioned to overwrite the file. I *guess* that if an overwrite is needed, it should be automatically done by `netcdf.renameVar`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know matlab, just python, but I'm guessing it is something like you used in your first example. ncwrite(ncid). Or perhaps just close the file.

Comment: As @EricBridger said, be sure you close the file to flush changes to file. Moreover, to be sure, after renaming, close matlab and do the ncdump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `netcdf.sync` or `netcdf.close`:

```
# ...
netcdf.renameVar(ncid,0,'velocity')
netcdf.sync(ncid)
```

or

```
# ...
netcdf.renameVar(ncid,0,'velocity')
netcdf.close(ncid)
```

After `netcdf.sync` you can still use the netcdf id `ncid` (to make more changes for examples). This is not the case for `netcdf.close`.

It is not necessary to close matlab for these changes to be visible for other programs.

The function call `netcdf.reDef` and `netcdf.endDef` are only needed when using NetCDF 3 files [1].

[1] https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2007/nc4features/Enddef.html